# Transforming coordinates from an image control to the image source in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, stretch

I'm trying to learn WPF, so here's a simple question, I hope:

I have a window that contains an Image element bound to a separate data object with user-configurable `Stretch` property

```
<Image Name="imageCtrl" Source="{Binding MyImage}" Stretch="{Binding ImageStretch}" />
```

When the user moves the mouse over the image, I would like to determine the coordinates of the mouse with respect to the *original image* (before stretching/cropping that occurs when it is displayed in the control), and then do something with those coordinates (update the image).

I know I can add an event-handler to the MouseMove event over the Image control, but I'm not sure how best to transform the coordinates:

```
void imageCtrl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point locationInControl = e.GetPosition(imageCtrl);
    Point locationInImage = ???
    updateImage(locationInImage);
}
```

Now I know I could compare the size of `Source` to the `ActualSize` of the control, and then switch on `imageCtrl.Stretch` to compute the scalars and offsets on X and Y, and do the transform myself.  But WPF has all the information already, and this seems like functionality that might be built-in to the WPF libraries somewhere.  So I'm wondering: is there a short and sweet solution?  Or do I need to write this myself?

---

**EDIT** I'm appending my current, not-so-short-and-sweet solution.  Its not that bad, but I'd be somewhat suprised if WPF didn't provide this functionality automatically:

```
Point ImgControlCoordsToPixelCoords(Point locInCtrl, 
    double imgCtrlActualWidth, double imgCtrlActualHeight)
{
    if (ImageStretch == Stretch.None)
        return locInCtrl;

    Size renderSize = new Size(imgCtrlActualWidth, imgCtrlActualHeight);
    Size sourceSize = bitmap.Size;

    double xZoom = renderSize.Width / sourceSize.Width;
    double yZoom = renderSize.Height / sourceSize.Height;

    if (ImageStretch == Stretch.Fill)
        return new Point(locInCtrl.X / xZoom, locInCtrl.Y / yZoom);

    double zoom;
    if (ImageStretch == Stretch.Uniform)
        zoom = Math.Min(xZoom, yZoom);
    else // (imageCtrl.Stretch == Stretch.UniformToFill)
        zoom = Math.Max(xZoom, yZoom);

    return new Point(locInCtrl.X / zoom, locInCtrl.Y / zoom);
}
```

Comment: Personally I'd probably do it exactly as your have in your "not-so-short-and-sweet" solution. I haven't run into a built in library that would do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would probably be easier if you used a ViewBox. For example:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="{Binding ImageStretch}">
    <Image Name="imageCtrl" Source="{Binding MyImage}" Stretch="None"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Then when you go and call GetPosition(..) WPF will automatically account for the scaling.

```
void imageCtrl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Point locationInControl = e.GetPosition(imageCtrl);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I found that I didn't need to set the HorizontalAlignment, but it was important to set the DPI for the Image source to 96 (I was using a non-standard bitmap).   Oh, and the 'b' in `Viewbox` is lowercase :)

Comment: Amazing! It is just awesome how easy it can be done in WPF!
Thanks a lot, saved my time.